# How to customize the breaks of y axis by using seq function in a loop in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have 3 datasets:

```
df[[1]]<-data.frame(x=(1,2,3,4,5),y=(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),id=rep("pic1",5))
df[[2]]<-data.frame(x=(1,2,3,4,5),y=(1,2,3,4,5),id=rep("pic2",5))
df[[3]]<-data.frame(x=(1,2,3,4,5),y=(100,110,120,130,140),id=rep("pic3",5))
```

I'd like to plot the figure in a loop, and customize the breaks of y axis by using scale_y_continuous() in ggplot. For example, the setting of by in seq() could be 0.1, 1, 10 for each dataset, but I have no idea how to express it by using a function in the setting of by.

The code I used was as below:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  dat <- df[[i]]
  jpeg(file = paste(unique(df[[i]]$id), '.jpeg', sep = ''),width = 1152,height=600) #setting of output figure
  fig<-
    ggplot(df[[i]], aes(x = x, y = y, fill= x)) +
    geom_barplot() + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(floor(min(df[[i]]$y)),ceiling(max(df[[i]]$y)),
                                    by=?), #here is the part I have trouble with
                       limits = c(floor(min(df[[i]]$y)),ceiling(max(df[[i]]$y)))) 
  print(fig)
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: You could try setting `n.breaks` (for example `n.breaks = 5` for all data sets) in `scale_y_continuous` instead of `breaks`. It will provide "nice break labels" close to the number of breaks you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `max` to set an upper y axis limit only, the lower limit is always zero.
And use `pretty` to create the y axis breaks vectors.

Note also that the right function to plot the bars layer is `geom_col` since you already have y values. `geom_bar` computes the y's from the data which, in this case, is not needed.

```r
df <- list()
df[[1]]<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),y=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),id=rep("pic1",5))
df[[2]]<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),y=c(1,2,3,4,5),id=rep("pic2",5))
df[[3]]<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),y=c(100,110,120,130,140),id=rep("pic3",5))

library(ggplot2)

lims_list <- lapply(df, `[[`, 2L) |> 
  lapply(\(x) c(0, max(x)))

for (i in 1:3) {
  dat <- df[[i]]
  flname <- paste0(unique(df[[i]]$id), '.jpeg')
  brks <- pretty(lims_list[[i]])
  jpeg(file = flname, width = 1152, height=600) #setting of output figure
  fig <-
    ggplot(df[[i]], aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) +
    geom_col() + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = brks, limits = lims_list[[i]])
  print(fig)
  dev.off()
}
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-13 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>